# How do I read a string portion until the end of line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have txt file containing:

```
Match 30, Rajiv Gandhi Intl. Cricket Stadium, Hyderabad
Delhi Capitals won by 39 runs
Sunrisers Hyderabad
```

I want to read from stadium till the end of line

So the output should be

```
Stadium, Hyderabad
```

and want to do it for many lines, all printed till the end of line starting from a particular word

How can I do it

Comment: can you please share the code or txt file.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by the `find()` method of string and slicing the line from the founded index to the end.

```
lines = """
Match 30, Rajiv Gandhi Intl. Cricket Stadium, Hyderabad  
Delhi Capitals won by 39 runs  
Sunrisers Hyderabad
"""

for line in lines.split("\n"):
    if "Stadium" in line:
        print(line[line.find("Stadium"):])
```

And from file

```
with open(full_file_path) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "Stadium" in line:
        print(line[line.find("Stadium"):])
```

Output

```
Stadium, Hyderabad
```